# Does ASP.NET MVC3 offer an automatically generated help page similar to the WCF Help Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm just beginning to dabble in ASP.NET MVC3 to mock up a dummy web service.  I've done this before with WCF and found the automated help pages to be really useful.  Is there a similar feature provided by MVC3 to automatically document my service's interfaces?  If such a feature is not built-in as part of the framework, are there any tools to fill this gap?

I did find that this feature is on the roadmap for MVC4, but I could not find any information regarding MVC3.

[ASP.NET MVC4 Roadmap](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately they is nothing like this in ASP.NET MVC3.
But I think you are looking for something like the pages [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) can provide.
For example see the [Hello World](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) example.